# ¿ Leer archivos con carácteres especiales en Node js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy leyendo un archivo csv con fs de node y no lee tildes ni ningún carácter especial. De que manera puede leer todo el documento incluyendo los carácteres especiales.

Asi lo estoy haciendo

```
 var Papa = require('papaparse')
 var fs = require('fs')

 var inputFile = './info.csv'

 function getItemsFromFile(inputFile, handler) {
   fs.readFile(inputFile, (err, data) => {
   getItemsFromString(data.toString(), handler)
 })
}

function getItemsFromString(data, handler) {
  var results = Papa.parse(data, { delimiter: ";" })
  handler(null, results.data)
}
```

Agradezco de antemanano sus respuestas.

Comment: por favor lee [ask] y añade lo que llevas, de otro modo es imposible saber que te este faltando

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863905/reading-from-file-containing-accented-characters-in-nodejs